# Static libstdc++ when cross-compiling for ARM while using Qt5

Tags: c++, linker, g++, qt5, cross-compiling

I have a ARM platform with an old libstdc++. I'm cross-compiling the application from other platform and I wanted to use more advanced features of C++ language so I'm linking my libstdc++ statically. I'm using Conan for package manager with plenty of other dynamic libraries and everything is running smoothly.

Problem arises when I try to add a totally new component of the application, which has been written in Qt5. Suddenly the stringstream have stopped working - the app doesn't crash, but the operator<<(int) resets the good bit in the stream.

'objdump -TC' on the executable shows that lot of the libstdc++ functions are now imported (linked dynamically) instead of linked statically.

Example:

```
0000000000000000      DF *UND*  0000000000000000  Qt_5        std::ostream::operator<<(int)
```

Notice the version "Qt_5".

I have also disassembled my executable to see that all calls to std::ostream::operator<<(int) are indeed calling imported symbol.

When I have tried to resolve libstdc++ symbols manually before g++ linker with

```
/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-ld -r -o out.o main.cpp.o /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/libstdc++.a
```

it worked as expected and there weren't any imported symbols related to ostream in the executable anymore and the stringstream works.

Any ideas regarding my situation?

Below is the command for linking executed by CLion. With this combination the application doesn't  work.

```
/usr/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++-7  -fPIC -static-libstdc++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Weffc++ -Wshadow -Wstrict-aliasing -Woverloaded-virtual -Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-unused-function -Wno-missing-braces  -g -rdynamic  -L/enviro/rv-linux/lib-target -L/enviro/rv-linux/targetfs/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu -Wl,-rpath,$ORIGIN/lib -Wl,-rpath,/enviro/rv-linux/lib-target  CMakeFiles/wwrk_core.dir/src/main.cpp.o  -o bin/wwrk_core -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/ukita-1.2/targets/aarch64-Linux/lib:/usr/local/cuda/targets/aarch64-linux/lib:/usr/local/cuda/targets/aarch64-linux/lib/stubs:/home/wwrk/.conan/data/mosquitto/1.4.15/bincrafters/stable/package/239078edbc0e8a96a9afdcfb7771317f2343a587/lib:/home/wwrk/.conan/data/OpenSSL/1.0.2o/conan/stable/package/7dd5184ee7a9467ffac8b88942d33774d1b75240/lib:/home/wwrk/.conan/data/Qt/5.11.2/bincrafters/stable/package/07bff7c90a07530ee2d9520bd150b7df4c4bcfd4/lib:/home/wwrk/.conan/data/Qt/5.11.2/bincrafters/stable/package/e7c3abf447189e454cc0dd043a04a91b61a54baf/lib:/usr/local/ukita/samples/3rdparty/linux-aarch64/special_Xlibs/lib: lib/libAnd_driver.a lib/libAndCore-dw.a /home/wwrk/.conan/data/OpenCV/3.4.0/wwrkauto/stable/package/2a79b1e5f5284318af316f0a3dad26795379cec1/lib/libopencv_dnn.a /home/wwrk/.conan/data/OpenCV/3.4.0/wwrkauto/stable/package/2a79b1e5f5284318af316f0a3dad26795379cec1/lib/libopencv_ml.a /home/wwrk/.conan/data/OpenCV/3.4.0/wwrkauto/stable/package/2a79b1e5f5284318af316f0a3dad26795379cec1/lib/libopencv_objdetect.a /home/wwrk/.conan/data/OpenCV/3.4.0/wwrkauto/stable/package/2a79b1e5f5284318af316f0a3dad26795379cec1/lib/libopencv_shape.a /home/wwrk/.conan/data/OpenCV/3.4.0/wwrkauto/stable/package/2a79b1e5f5284318af316f0a3dad26795379cec1/lib/libopencv_stitching.a /home/wwrk/.conan/data/OpenCV/3.4.0/wwrkauto/stable/package/2a79b1e5f5284318af316f0a3dad26795379cec1/lib/libopencv_superres.a /home/wwrk/.conan/data/OpenCV/3.4.0/wwrkauto/stable/package/2a79b1e5f5284318af316f0a3dad26795379cec1/lib/libopencv_videostab.a /home/wwrk/.conan/data/OpenCV/3.4.0/wwrkauto/stable/package/2a79b1e5f5284318af316f0a3dad26795379cec1/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib/liblibprotobuf.a /home/wwrk/.conan/data/OpenCV/3.4.0/wwrkauto/stable/package/2a79b1e5f5284318af316f0a3dad26795379cec1/lib/libopencv_calib3d.a /home/wwrk/.conan/data/OpenCV/3.4.0/wwrkauto/stable/package/2a79b1e5f5284318af316f0a3dad26795379cec1/lib/libopencv_features2d.a /home/wwrk/.conan/data/OpenCV/3.4.0/wwrkauto/stable/package/2a79b1e5f5284318af316f0a3dad26795379cec1/lib/libopencv_flann.a /home/wwrk/.conan/data/OpenCV/3.4.0/wwrkauto/stable/package/2a79b1e5f5284318af316f0a3dad26795379cec1/lib/libopencv_highgui.a -lgthread-2.0 /home/wwrk/.conan/data/OpenCV/3.4.0/wwrkauto/stable/package/2a79b1e5f5284318af316f0a3dad26795379cec1/lib/libopencv_photo.a /home/wwrk/.conan/data/OpenCV/3.4.0/wwrkauto/stable/package/2a79b1e5f5284318af316f0a3dad26795379cec1/lib/libopencv_video.a /home/wwrk/.conan/data/OpenCV/3.4.0/wwrkauto/stable/package/2a79b1e5f5284318af316f0a3dad26795379cec1/lib/libopencv_videoio.a /home/wwrk/.conan/data/OpenCV/3.4.0/wwrkauto/stable/package/2a79b1e5f5284318af316f0a3dad26795379cec1/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.a /home/wwrk/.conan/data/OpenCV/3.4.0/wwrkauto/stable/package/2a79b1e5f5284318af316f0a3dad26795379cec1/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib/libIlmImf.a /home/wwrk/.conan/data/OpenCV/3.4.0/wwrkauto/stable/package/2a79b1e5f5284318af316f0a3dad26795379cec1/lib/libopencv_imgproc.a /home/wwrk/.conan/data/OpenCV/3.4.0/wwrkauto/stable/package/2a79b1e5f5284318af316f0a3dad26795379cec1/lib/libopencv_core.a -lgstbase-1.0 -lgstreamer-1.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lgstvideo-1.0 -lgstapp-1.0 -lgstriff-1.0 -lgstpbutils-1.0 /home/wwrk/.conan/data/jasper/2.0.14/conan/stable/package/06e35b3c6107222c50e1c22eae68c58d483cba15/lib/libjasper.a /home/wwrk/.conan/data/libjpeg/9b/bincrafters/stable/package/e6d649ca4bea46777eed92a123bea4d2c1892ea8/lib/libjpeg.a /home/wwrk/.conan/data/libpng/1.6.34/bincrafters/stable/package/42e51281839943ca78313263055e6869dd2d2f9a/lib/libpng16.a /home/wwrk/.conan/data/libwebp/0.6.1/bincrafters/stable/package/b85d569a3b57b77ebc11d00bbbe398c7753b32be/lib/libwebpdemux.a /home/wwrk/.conan/data/libwebp/0.6.1/bincrafters/stable/package/b85d569a3b57b77ebc11d00bbbe398c7753b32be/lib/libwebp.a /home/wwrk/.conan/data/libwebp/0.6.1/bincrafters/stable/package/b85d569a3b57b77ebc11d00bbbe398c7753b32be/lib/libwebpdecoder.a -lusb-1.0 -ludev /usr/local/ukita-1.2/targets/aarch64-Linux/lib/libukita.so /usr/local/cuda/targets/aarch64-linux/lib/libcudart.so /enviro/rv-linux/targetfs/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgstsdp-1.0.so /enviro/rv-linux/targetfs/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so /enviro/rv-linux/targetfs/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgstapp-1.0.so /enviro/rv-linux/targetfs/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-1.0.so /enviro/rv-linux/targetfs/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgstnet-1.0.so /enviro/rv-linux/targetfs/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so /enviro/rv-linux/targetfs/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgio-2.0.so /enviro/rv-linux/targetfs/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so /enviro/rv-linux/targetfs/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so /usr/local/cuda/targets/aarch64-linux/lib/stubs/libcublas.so -lstdc++fs -lcuda lib/libAndCore-core.a -lpthread -lrt /home/wwrk/.conan/data/mosquitto/1.4.15/bincrafters/stable/package/239078edbc0e8a96a9afdcfb7771317f2343a587/lib/libmosquitto.so /home/wwrk/.conan/data/mosquitto/1.4.15/bincrafters/stable/package/239078edbc0e8a96a9afdcfb7771317f2343a587/lib/libmosquittopp.so -ldl /home/wwrk/.conan/data/OpenSSL/1.0.2o/conan/stable/package/7dd5184ee7a9467ffac8b88942d33774d1b75240/lib/libssl.so /home/wwrk/.conan/data/OpenSSL/1.0.2o/conan/stable/package/7dd5184ee7a9467ffac8b88942d33774d1b75240/lib/libcrypto.so /home/wwrk/.conan/data/zlib/1.2.11/conan/stable/package/8fd38d381db52e2495321ce060b9f457656f6c8f/lib/libz.a /home/wwrk/.conan/data/c-ares/1.14.0/conan/stable/package/8fd38d381db52e2495321ce060b9f457656f6c8f/lib/libcares.a -lm /home/wwrk/.conan/data/yaml-cpp/0.6.2/bincrafters/stable/package/08f0f6b54224d0f59c7a23bfbaa25f463db315ae/lib/libyaml-cpp.a -latomic lib/libAndautoDashboard.a /home/wwrk/.conan/data/Qt/5.11.2/bincrafters/stable/package/e7c3abf447189e454cc0dd043a04a91b61a54baf/lib/libQt5Location.so.5.11.2 /home/wwrk/.conan/data/Qt/5.11.2/bincrafters/stable/package/e7c3abf447189e454cc0dd043a04a91b61a54baf/lib/libQt5PositioningQuick.so.5.11.2 /home/wwrk/.conan/data/Qt/5.11.2/bincrafters/stable/package/e7c3abf447189e454cc0dd043a04a91b61a54baf/lib/libQt5Positioning.so.5.11.2 /home/wwrk/.conan/data/Qt/5.11.2/bincrafters/stable/package/e7c3abf447189e454cc0dd043a04a91b61a54baf/lib/libQt53DQuick.so.5.11.2 /home/wwrk/.conan/data/Qt/5.11.2/bincrafters/stable/package/e7c3abf447189e454cc0dd043a04a91b61a54baf/lib/libQt5Quick.so.5.11.2 /home/wwrk/.conan/data/Qt/5.11.2/bincrafters/stable/package/e7c3abf447189e454cc0dd043a04a91b61a54baf/lib/libQt5Qml.so.5.11.2 /home/wwrk/.conan/data/Qt/5.11.2/bincrafters/stable/package/e7c3abf447189e454cc0dd043a04a91b61a54baf/lib/libQt53DExtras.so.5.11.2 /home/wwrk/.conan/data/Qt/5.11.2/bincrafters/stable/package/e7c3abf447189e454cc0dd043a04a91b61a54baf/lib/libQt53DInput.so.5.11.2 /home/wwrk/.conan/data/Qt/5.11.2/bincrafters/stable/package/e7c3abf447189e454cc0dd043a04a91b61a54baf/lib/libQt5Gamepad.so.5.11.2 /home/wwrk/.conan/data/Qt/5.11.2/bincrafters/stable/package/e7c3abf447189e454cc0dd043a04a91b61a54baf/lib/libQt53DLogic.so.5.11.2 /home/wwrk/.conan/data/Qt/5.11.2/bincrafters/stable/package/e7c3abf447189e454cc0dd043a04a91b61a54baf/lib/libQt53DAnimation.so.5.11.2 /home/wwrk/.conan/data/Qt/5.11.2/bincrafters/stable/package/e7c3abf447189e454cc0dd043a04a91b61a54baf/lib/libQt53DRender.so.5.11.2 /home/wwrk/.conan/data/Qt/5.11.2/bincrafters/stable/package/e7c3abf447189e454cc0dd043a04a91b61a54baf/lib/libQt53DCore.so.5.11.2 /home/wwrk/.conan/data/Qt/5.11.2/bincrafters/stable/package/07bff7c90a07530ee2d9520bd150b7df4c4bcfd4/lib/libQt5Network.so.5.11.2 /home/wwrk/.conan/data/Qt/5.11.2/bincrafters/stable/package/e7c3abf447189e454cc0dd043a04a91b61a54baf/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5.11.2 /home/wwrk/.conan/data/Qt/5.11.2/bincrafters/stable/package/e7c3abf447189e454cc0dd043a04a91b61a54baf/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5.11.2 /home/wwrk/.conan/data/Qt/5.11.2/bincrafters/stable/package/07bff7c90a07530ee2d9520bd150b7df4c4bcfd4/lib/libQt5Core.so.5.11.2 -Wl,-Bstatic -lstdc++ -Wl,-Bdynamic -lX11 /home/wwrk/workdir/GST/libs/glfw/libglfw3.a -Wl,-Bstatic -lstdc++ -Wl,-Bdynamic -lX11 /home/wwrk/workdir/GST/libs/glfw/libglfw3.a /usr/local/ukita/samples/3rdparty/linux-aarch64/special_Xlibs/lib/libXcursor.so /usr/local/ukita/samples/3rdparty/linux-aarch64/special_Xlibs/lib/libXi.so /usr/local/ukita/samples/3rdparty/linux-aarch64/special_Xlibs/lib/libXrandr.so /usr/local/ukita/samples/3rdparty/linux-aarch64/special_Xlibs/lib/libXinerama.so /enviro/rv-linux/lib-target/libGLESv2.so.2 /enviro/rv-linux/targetfs/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so -lEGL -lGLU
```

Thank you for answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem. I needed to explicitly list static version of standard library on the top of the lib list. It's very far from ideal solution, but now the bin got built as I intended.

```
if(${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} MATCHES ".*aarch64.*")
LIST(APPEND SAMPLE_LIBRARIES
     /usr/lib/gcc-cross/aarch64-linux-gnu/7/libstdc++.a
)
endif()
...
#other libraries here
```